# All pairwise non-isomorphic abelian groups of order 67500?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$67500=2^2*3^3*5^4$ => $2*3*4=24$ pairwise non-isomorphic abelian groups.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't multiply the exponents but the product of the numbers of integer partitions of the exponents.

As  $2=1+1$ and $2=2$ and $3=1+2=1+1+1$ and $4=1+1+1+1=2+1+1=2+2=3+1$ you have
$$ 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5=30$$ non isomorphic abelian groups.

This is because of the classification theorem for finite abelian groups states, that when $G$ is finite and abelian, then 
$$G\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}/p_i^{v_i}\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Are you sure its correct? For example $18=2^1*3^2$, by your method it would have $6$ non isomorphic abelian groups. But it has only $2$ of them.

Comment: @blondy You should try to read it again. The actual primes involved are unimportant.

Comment: @Blondy, what Tobias says is that If $n = \prod p_i^{k_1}$ and $\pi(k)$ denotes the number of integer partitions of $k$, then the number of distinct abelian groups of order $n$ is $\prod \pi(k_i)$.

Comment: Sorry I am still not getting it. Where is the $2*3*5$ coming from? Precisely where is the $5$ coming from?

Comment: Oh wait, now I am getting it. $4$ can be partitioned in five  ways. $4, 1+1+1+1,2+2,2+1+1,3+1$.

Comment: @Blondy, yep, that's it!

Answer (score 2):

By the [Classification Theorem for Finite Abelian Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group), all finite abelian groups are isomorphic to $$\mathbb{Z}_{q_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q_2} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{q_t}$$ where $q_1,\ldots,q_t$ are $t$ not necessarily distinct prime powers.

Consequently, the number of finite abelian groups of order $p^k$ for some prime $p$ is the number of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $k$.  For example, the number of groups of order $p^4$, for prime $p$, are tabulated below.

$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\text{partition} & \text{abelian group} \\
4 & \mathbb{Z}_{p^4} \\
3 + 1 & \mathbb{Z}_{p^3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \\
2 + 2 & \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \\
2 + 1 + 1 & \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \\
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 & \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \\
\end{array}$$

We can also deduce that if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then the abelian groups of order $p^k q^r$ are isomorphic to $G \times H$ where $G$ is an abelian group of order $p^k$ and $H$ is an abelian group of order $q^r$.

So, if $\pi_n$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$, we have:

- The number of abelian groups of order $p^k$ for prime $p$ is $\pi_k$.
- The number of abelian groups of order $p^k q^r$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q$ is $\pi_k \pi_r$.
- And so on.